# Nativescript transparent row gridlayout

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a grid layout with a fixed header and navbar and a scrollview for the page

```
<GridLayout rows="50, *, 50">
<StackLayout row="0">
    // header
</StackLayout>

<ScrollView row="1">
    <StackLayout>
        // page
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

<StackLayout row="2">
    // nav
</StackLayout>
```

I'm trying to float images over the scrollview (it's part of the header) and the images have transparency. I want the scrollview to be able to scroll while fixed images are over it.

I've tried absolute layouts, rows #s that are the same, everything.

What would be ideal would be to have a gridrow that has a transparent middle that I can put over the scrollview.

Comment: Have you tried StackLayout as well?

Comment: If I understood your query correct, I don't really see any issues in there. [Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=afYWWQ) is a Playground sample.

Comment: Close @Manoj https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=afYWWQ&v=3

Comment: See how where the row is transparents (where it curves) the text disappears?  I'm trying to make it to visible there.

Comment: And yes @NarendraMongiya I've tried just about everything including stacklayout, been at it for hours.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to see the text moving behind the header image while scrolling?

Comment: Right@Manoj where its transparent in the header I want to be able to still see it.

Comment: I edited and added a visual representation of my end goal. I didn't think something so simple would be so hard to accomplish in nativescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `isUserInteractionEnabled` view property.

```
<GridLayout>
  <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout> <!-- content --> </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  <StackLayout isUserInteractionEnabled="false"> <!-- overlay --> </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

**Example:**
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=afYWWQ&v=5